# CrawlSpider callback function in RULE never been called

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I want to scrape all tags on http://quotes.toscrape.com/,using `scrapy 2.2`,code is below

i got output like this:

> "DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET [http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/classic/page/1/>](http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/classic/page/1/%3E) (referer: http://quotes.toscrape.com)".

So the link_extractor is working ,but why the `callback` never executed?

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
name = 'quotes'
#allowed_domains = ['quotes.toscrape.com']
start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com']

rules = (
    #extract links to tag page
    Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="tags"]')),callback='parse_tag'),
    #Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r'/author/', )), callback='parse_author')
)
def parse_tag(self,response):
    taginfo=ItemLoader(item=tagitem(),response=response)
    taginfo.add_xpath('tag','//h3/a/text()')
    taginfo.add_xpath('quote','//span[@class="text"]/text()')
    return taginfo.load_item()
```

Answer (score 0):

Its Work for me. Its may help you.

```
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader

from scrapy import item, Field

class LinkfinderItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    url = Field()
    anchor_text = Field()

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'quotesx'
    #allowed_domains = ['quotes.toscrape.com']
    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com']

    rules = (
        #extract links to tag page
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="tags"]')), callback='parse_tag'),
        #Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r'/author/', )), callback='parse_author')
    )
    def parse_tag(self,response):

        tags = response.css('div.tags a.tag')

        for tag in tags:
            l = ItemLoader(item=LinkfinderItem(),selector=tag)
            l.add_value('url', response.url)
            l.add_value('anchor_text', response.css('div.tags a.tag::text').extract())
            yield l.load_item()
```

Comment: why our codes is basically same but mine's just don't work?

Comment: Please check your tagitem()

Comment: The 'item' is fine,porblem is for some reason it just don't exectue my 'callback' fuction

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.The parse_tag define is out #MysSpider#,and that's why it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Your callback method is getting called. You can print the response to verify this.

Try

```
def parse_tag(self, response):
    print(response.text)
```